# How to follow a person from the registered twitter account in the device using Twitter SDK

Tags: android, twitter, oauth, twitter4j, twitter-fabric

I am working on a project wherein i have a requirement to follow a person using Twitter. For that purpose I am using Twitter SDK along with the OAuth `ConsumerKey`, `ConsumerSecret`, `AccessToken` and `AccessTokenSecret`. Everything works fine but I am completely stuck up with the things to follow the user based on the registered twitter account in the device.

**What I tried**

I have tried to follow a user based on the OAuth tokens generated for my application from the `apps.twitter.com`. Please find the below method that I am using to follow a person

```
private void doTwitterTask() {

        screenName = "takeoffandroid";
        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();

        cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
                .setOAuthConsumerKey("cgUkuXrGyKcVhdRzxPI2tpwtk")
                .setOAuthConsumerSecret("9h3UX66UvLSNh5nVKMDkd23JDMAgj3rFKVEgFNyRiXAKG")
                .setOAuthAccessToken("3890921658-EGdpl6u2H89JDMkaFDaLM5vN3adclEKJLa2nED")
                .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("Q3HFkgPCuO7LiPAFakQDKK89CDA1H5PK");

        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
        Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
        try {
            twitter.createFriendship(screenName);
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            Log.d("MCG","Error");
        }
    }
```

The above method works fine but the follow count is submitted from the main account where i have **registered the application** from `apps.twitter.com` not from the **device registered user account**. Please help me how to proceed with my requirement. Any kind of hint and tips would be helpful to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you do not get any answers here, you might try [the official Twitter developer support forums](https://twittercommunity.com/). I have never used the official Twitter SDK.